# Select 1 row from select statement php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT questionid, surveyid, question, responsetype, imageid FROM questions WHERE surveyid = " . $_POST['survey'] .";";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(3);
```

I'm trying to get the 3rd row of this select statement. The last line didn't work and returns the first line and I've been trying for an hour looking around StackOverflow and the PHP website and can't find anything. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [`LIMIT` clause](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) in your SQL statement:

```
$query = "SELECT questionid, surveyid, question, responsetype, imageid 
FROM questions WHERE surveyid = " . $_POST['survey'] ." LIMIT 2,1;";
```

The `2` means start at the third row (remember we start counting at zero) and the `1` means return one row.

Comment: I know about the SQL injections. I was just trying to make it work. I had other code that was better but it was easier to test with that code.

Comment: @Clarkinator thats not obvious to future readers - its not good to promote bad patterns.